# Is std::vector::data() reallocation-safe?

Tags: c++, pointers, stdvector

As far as I know, taking a pointer or reference to `std::vector` element is considered bad practice. But what about `std::vector::data()`? Does the pointer taken by `data()` remain valid after reallocation?

Comment: No it doesn't remain valid after a reallocation.

Comment: Nope. All pointers and iterators are invalidated on reallocation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As far as I know, taking a pointer or reference to std::vector element considered as bad practice.

References and pointers can avoid copying overhead, which is not a bad practice if you can ensure that the `std::vector` will not be reallocated during the reference or pointer lifetime.

(BTW, in C++, there is no need to use pointers when you can use references)

> But what about std::vector::data()? Does the pointer taken by data() remain valid after reallocation?

No. Reallocation may cause the pointer to change. Using the old pointer after reallocation is an undefined behavior. Same for iterators.

Comment: Completely agree. It's not *taking* pointers or references what should be discouraged, but *storing* (especially in non-local variables like members of objects) pointers or references to vector elements.